# Glitch in Vue in production

Tags: javascript, nginx, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

When I'm running locally using `yarn serve`, the website is working perfectly fine.
However, when I try running `yarn build` and open the production version locally (using an Nginx server, if it matters) and then opening a certain globally-registered component via Vue Router, I keep getting an error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

After a little trial and error, it seems there's a problem with globally registering components.
Note that I have a non-global component as well, yet it is possible to open it.

This is how I currently register them:

```
function registerComponentsGlobally() {
  const requireComponent = require.context("./components/products", false, /\.vue/);
  const keys = requireComponent.keys();
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    const fileName = keys[i];
    const componentConfig = requireComponent(fileName);
    const componentName = fileName.split("/").pop().replace(/\.\w+$/, "");
    Vue.component(componentName, componentConfig.default || componentConfig);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, I could wrongly register them in Vue Router:

```
async function initializeVue() {
  const products = await fetch("products.json").then(data => data.json());

  function toRoutes(routes, {pageUrl, platforms: {0: {isExternal}}}) {
    if (!isExternal) {
      routes.push({
        path: `/${pageUrl}`,
        name: pageUrl,
        component: () => import(`./components/products/${pageUrl}`),
      });
    }
    return routes;
  }

  new Vue({
    router: new Router({
      mode: "history",
      routes: [...defaultRoutes, ...products.reduce(toRoutes, [])],
    }),
    ...
```

In the [Vue Router's History Mode documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations), I copied the Nginx code to my configuration file, plus the assets load correctly, so it seems there isn't a problem.

What am I missing?
Thank you for helping!

**EDIT**: Here's the stack trace if it's relevant:

```
vue-router.esm.js:1921 TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at a (.*$ namespace object:90)
    at component (main.js:27)
    at vue-router.esm.js:1790
    at vue-router.esm.js:1817
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at vue-router.esm.js:1817
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Rt (vue-router.esm.js:1816)
    at vue-router.esm.js:1752
    at h (vue-router.esm.js:1959)
    at r (vue-router.esm.js:1733)
    at r (vue-router.esm.js:1737)
    at r (vue-router.esm.js:1737)
    at Pt (vue-router.esm.js:1741)
    at e.zt.confirmTransition (vue-router.esm.js:1988)
    at e.zt.transitionTo (vue-router.esm.js:1890)
    at e.replace (vue-router.esm.js:2212)
    at ue.replace (vue-router.esm.js:2585)
    at a.routeToProduct (product-links.vue:44)
    at ne (vue.runtime.esm.js:1854)
    at HTMLButtonElement.n (vue.runtime.esm.js:2179)
    at HTMLButtonElement.Zi.o._wrapper (vue.runtime.esm.js:6911)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but I managed to get it working by changing:

```
function toRoutes(routes, {pageUrl, platforms: {0: {isExternal}}}) {
  if (!isExternal) {
    routes.push({
      path: `/${pageUrl}`,
      name: pageUrl,
      component: () => import(`./components/products/${pageUrl}`),
    });
  }
  return routes;
}
```

to:

```
function toRoutes(routes, {pageUrl, platforms: {0: {isExternal}}}) {
  if (!isExternal) {
    // Extracted the directory to a variable
    const dir = `./components/products`;
    routes.push({
      path: `/${pageUrl}`,
      name: pageUrl,
      component: () => import(`${dir}/${pageUrl}`),
    });
  }
  return routes;
}
```